# How do I determine the weight to assign to each bucket?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra, probability, linear-regression, linear-programming

Someone will answer a series of questions and will mark each important (I), very important (V), or extremely important (E). I'll then match their answers with answers given by everyone else, compute the percent of the answers in each bucket that are the same, then combine the percentages to get a final score.

For example, I answer 10 questions, marking 3 as extremely important, 5 as very important, and 2 as important. I then match my answers with someone else's, and they answer the same to 2/3 extremely important questions, 4/5 very important questions, and 2/2 important questions. This results in percentages of 66.66 (extremely important), 80.00 (very important), and 100.00 (important). I then combine these 3 percentages to get a final score, but I first weigh each percentage to reflect the importance of each bucket. So the result would be something like: score = E * 66.66 + V * 80.00 + I * 100.00. The values of E, V, and I (the weights) are what I'm trying to figure out how to calculate.

The following are the constraints present:

1 + X + X^2 = X^3

E >= X * V >= X^2 * I > 0

E + V + I = 1

E + 0.9 * V >= 0.9

0.9 > 0.9 * E + 0.75 * V >= 0.75

E + I < 0.75

When combining the percentages, I could give important a weight of 0.0749, very important a weight of .2501, and extremely important a weight of 0.675, but this seems arbitrary, so I'm wondering how to go about calculating the optimal value for each weight. Also, how do I calculate the optimal weights if I ignore all constraints?

As far as what I mean by optimal: while adhering to the last 4 constraints, I want the weight of each bucket to be the maximum possible value, while having the weights be as far apart as possible (extremely important questions weighted maximally more than very important questions, and very important questions weighted maximally more than important questions).

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear as to what the 'score' should quantify? Is it the closeness between two people rating the questions? Also, you mention wanting to find 'optimal' values. What metric are you using to define what optimal is?

Comment: @DanielJohnson the score is the percentage of questions user A and user B answered the same, where answering an extremely important question the same counts more than answering a very important question the same. As far as what I mean by optimal: while adhering to the last 4 constraints, I want the weight of each bucket to be the maximum possible value, while having the weights be as far apart as possible (extremely important questions weighted maximally more than very important questions, and very important questions weighted maximally more than important questions).

Comment: It seems like you want to optimize two things: 1) the magnitude of weights and 2) the spread between weights. 

The first does not seem well formed since you also want to impose a fixed sum of weights (1 = I + V + E). As for the second, to truly optimize 'spread', we must find a way to quantify it.